# sum rule for integrals in mean

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, average, means

if I have a mean
\begin{equation}
\langle (a+b)^2 \rangle
\end{equation}
is this then equal to 
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{T} \int\limits_{0}^{t} a^2 + \frac{1}{T} \int\limits_{0}^{t} 2ab + \frac{1}{T} \int\limits_{0}^{t} b^2 
\end{equation}
because of the sum rule for integrals?

Comment: What are $T$ and $t$ here. What are you integrating with respect to?

Comment: $t$ time and $T$ time for full period

Comment: Integrating with respect to what?

Comment: integration with respect to time dt